# How can you pass a large amount of textures or equivalent to the fragment shader in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, shaders, fragment-shader, shadows, shadow-mapping

I am adding shadow mapping to a game engine I am working on.

For this effect, each light source needs it's own associated shadow map cube texture.

I am going to be exaggerated and say there can be up to 1000 lights in the world at a given time (this would most likely lag the entire thing, but that's not the issue).

This means I need up to 1000 depth maps loaded into the shaders at any one time.

According to:

```
GLint temp; 
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS, &temp);
cout << temp << endl;
```

I have up to 4 texture units available. And the way I am currently passing my shadow maps is:

```
void Shadow_Map::load_to_GPU(GLuint program, GLuint index)
{   
    glUseProgram(program);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+index+1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureID);

    string name = "depth_maps[" + to_string(index) + "]";

    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, name.c_str());
    if(loc == GL_INVALID_VALUE || loc==GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
    {
        cerr << "Error returned when trying to find depth_map uniform."
             << endl;
        return;
    }

    glUniform1i(loc,1+index);
}
```

So under my current methods I am very far away from the amount of depth map cube textures I need to use. Is there a better way to pass a large amount of cubicTextures, or what other techinique could I use to be able to handle large amounts of point lights?

Comment: "Many point lights" sounds like you're right in the wheelhouse of deferred rendering.

Comment: "*I have up to 4 texture units available.*" That's compatibility OpenGL. A core profile would have given you an error. The maximum number of [texture *image* units](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Binding_textures_to_samplers) for a fragment shader is `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`.

Comment: Also, note that a 512x512 depth cubemap, even at 16-bit precision, requires 3 MB. Therefore, storing 1000 of them would require 3 GB. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [Cube Map Texture Array](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Cubemap_Texture#Cubemap_array_textures) for this.  You can query the maximum array texture layers with:

```
GLuint max_layers;
glGetIntegerv (GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS, &max_layers);
```

E.g. my implementation (NVIDIA) returns 2048.  Your mileage may vary with others.

I am raising my eyebrow slightly at the need for so many light sources.  It seems a little excessive.

As DMGregory mentions, [deferred shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_shading) is a preferred solution for many light sources, however even there you aren't going to generate a unique shadow map for each.  It's not trivial to implement well either.

Comment: "*my implementation (NVIDIA) returns 2048. Your mileage may vary with others.*" Note that for cubemap arrays, the maximum number of array texture layers is actually the number of *layer faces*. So the maximum number of cubemap array layers would be 2048 / 6 = 341.

Comment: Ah, good point Nicol.